# How do I ensure that php script gives enough time for execution of MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance, sleep

I want to give my php script time to check queries.

My cycle:

1. Choose value
2. --- I want (maybe here?) some delay, sleep or something ---
3. MySQL SELECT Query
4. Compare values depending on SELECT results

Points 3 and 4 can theoretically take about 2 seconds.

Will PHP wait until the SELECT is complete?

Or will php wait for filling big arrays? (multidimensional, about 250 * 5 * 2 values..)

Answer (score 1):

Php execution is always sequential. You do not need to have any delays or sleep.

Comment: I thought it. But, how is it possible, that my functions for parsing data from array string are empty? $string = "first, second, third" ... takeFirst($string) , takeSecond($string) ... etc, I don't understand. It looks like php needs to be faster or something..

Comment: Post some code.You can edit your answer and add formated code